# Out of bounds array exception for one line and not the other?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, stringtokenizer

CODE

```
 ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PRINT = new ArrayList<String>();

    String tok = "";

    for(String element : list) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(element);

        if(!element.startsWith("PRINT")) {
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tok = st.nextToken();
                tokens.add(tok);

                for(String key : expression.keySet())
                    if(tok.equals(key))
                        System.out.println(tokens.get(0) + " changed from " + expression.get(key) + " to " + Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2)));
            }

            expression.put(tokens.get(0),Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2)));
            tokens.clear();
        }
```

I am getting an array out of bounds exception at below line

```
System.out.println(tokens.get(0) + " changed from " + expression.get(key) + " to " + Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2))
```

I know that tokens.get(0) = "A", tokens.get(1) = "=" and tokens.get(2) = "7"

Comment: It seems what you know is incorrect

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Can you print token.size() before for loop just for cross check?

Comment: Take care `{}` block of inner `for loop` !!!

Comment: I guess the issue may be my file contains a line A = 6 but it's reading it as "A=6", any help on that ?

Comment: If you used a debugger you would be able to diagnose this yourself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of code

```
for(String element : list) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(element);

        if(!element.startsWith("PRINT")) {
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tok = st.nextToken();
                tokens.add(tok);
```

Use below code

```
for(String element : list) {

     for(int i=0;i<element.length();i++){         
           tokens.add(element.charAt(i)+"");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time you add a token to `tokens` there will be only one item, however your `for` loop requires 3 (at indexes 0, 1 and 2).

Comment: I guess the issue may be my file contains a line A = 6 but it's reading it as "A=6", any help on that ?